# Can't Restart Scene in unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have several levels, each one has 6 scenes, the scenes names are: Scene 1, Scene 2, Scene 3 ...etc...

When the player lose, the current scene should be restarted, so I used this code:

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
```

I didn't use "(...)GetActiveScene().name);" because the scenes names are repeated on each level.

The problem I have is when the player lose in level2 (scene 6), the scene 6 of level1 is loaded instead of restarting scene 6 of level2. Do you know what's the problem in my code?

Comment: Are you sure the buildIndex for the active scene is the number you're expecting? Something could have happened in the configuration to put the indexes out of sequence (at least that's happened to me before)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not an answer to why this happens in your specific case but two suggestions I would prefer:

Just a workaround but how about naming your scenes properly instead like e.g. `Level1_Scene1`, `Level2_Scene3` etc

so they are all uniquely identifiable using `GetActiveScene().name`

---

Alternatively you could also try using [`GetActiveScene().path`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-path.html) (which is allways unique) since  [`LoadScene`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html) takes

> Name or **path** of the Scene to load.

Comment: I never thought about using the path--that's a really great option without having to rename anything.

Comment: Using path is the best solution for me, because I can't rename the scenes. Thank you!